# Pass array of arrays in JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to pass an array of arrays from Android to a server using JSON. My JSON data is `time,longitude,latitude` in following format:

```
[[12/12/13 12:00:03,12.125455,35.123445]
[20/12/13 11:02:03,45.123456,78.111222]]
```

How can i pass that kind of data to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First of all object your are passing is not a valid JSON object so you have to pass a valid    JSON objet. You can use this link http://jsonlint.com/ to check/validate JSON.

2.Check your web service how it accepts JSON format and format it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a valid JSON string.

```
[["12/12/13 12:00:03","12.125455,35.123445"],["20/12/13 11:02:03","45.123456,78.111222"]]
```

I don't know if the data format is "set in stone", but you could also pass this as an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "long" : "12/12/13 12:00:03",
        "lat"  : "12.125455,35.123445"
    },
    {
        "long" : "20/12/13 11:02:03",
        "lat"  : "45.123456,78.111222"
    }
]
```

This way you can access the properties of each coordinate as something like `coord.long` and `coord.lat` instead of `coord[0]` and `coord[1]`.

Comment: Thanks verymuch Aaron can u give me code example for that & i have 3 values time, long, lat not 2